# React-native-camera, run a fucntion if user denies camera permission

Tags: react-native, react-native-camera

I have RNCamera set up as follows:

```
          <RNCamera
                ref={ref => {
                    this.camera = ref;
                }}
                orientation='portrait'
                captureAudio={false}
                androidCameraPermissionOptions={{
                    title: 'Permission to use camera',
                    message: 'We need your permission to use your camera',
                    buttonPositive: 'Ok',
                    buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
                }}
                androidRecordAudioPermissionOptions={{
                    title: 'Permission to use audio recording',
                    message: 'We need your permission to use your audio',
                    buttonPositive: 'Ok',
                    buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
                }}
                style={styles.camera}>
          </RNCamera>
```

I want to run a callback if the user denies permission, but I can't seem to find anything to allow me to do this. 
I also tried to attach a callback when buttonNegative is pressed but that didn't work either.

I also tried to use the onStatusChange function:

```
  onStatusChange={(cameraStatus) => {
      if (cameraStatus === "NOT_AUTHORIZED") {
          this.closeCameraOverlay()
      }
  }}
```

Any guidance would be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

> camerstatus is the object inside we have two value `
>
> {"cameraStatus": "NOT_AUTHORIZED", "recordAudioPermissionStatus":
> "NOT_AUTHORIZED"}

```
  onStatusChange={(cameraStatus) => {
                console.log(cameraStatus)
                if (cameraStatus.cameraStatus === "NOT_AUTHORIZED") {
                    this.closeCameraOverlay()
                }
            }}
```